# Inconsistent dispatcher.Invoke behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

I have created a wallboard application for a service desk team, which uses WPF for front-end and the Cisco database of the phones in the back-end. The application is made of two screens that show different information, and these are displayed in the same screen and change between each other with a `System.Timers.Timer`.
The application is made so that if `WindowA` is visible, `WindowB` is shown and then `WindowA` is hidden. The moment one of the Windows becomes visible, that Window's timer become active again which resumes the database calls, while the other Window's timer becomes disabled:

```
private static void InterfaceChanger_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowA.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        WindowAEnabled = false;
        ChangeVisibility(Visibility.Visible, WindowB);
        WindowBEnabled = true;
        WindowB_Elapsed(null, null); // force the call of the timer's callback
        ChangeVisibility(Visibility.Collapsed, WindowA);
    }
    else
    {
        WindowBEnabled = false;
        ChangeVisibility(Visibility.Visible, WindowA);
        WindowAEnabled = true;
        WindowA_Elapsed(null, null);  // force the call of the timer's callback
        ChangeVisibility(Visibility.Collapsed, WindowB);
    }
}

private static void ChangeVisibility(Visibility visibility, Window window)
{
    window.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (SendOrPostCallback)delegate
    {
        window.Visibility = visibility;
    }, null);
}
```

The problem is that this works perfectly... at most 90% of the time. The problem is that sometimes, if for example `WindowA's` visibility is changed to Visible and `WindowB's` visibility is changed to Collapsed, `WindowB` collapses but `WindowA` takes 2-3 seconds to become visible, while most times `WindowA` becomes visible and it's not seen when `WindowB` collapses. This (when it doesn't work) results in the Desktop being visible instead of the application.
I originally used `DispatcherPriority.Background` but that resulted in the screen changer working 70-80% of the time, so I decided to change it for `DispatcherPriority.Normal` (`DispatcherPriority.Send`results basically in the same situation as Normal).

Questions:

1. Is this the normal behavior to be expected by the Dispatcher, taking into account this is running in x64 mode in a quad-core CPU?
2. Knowing that the queries are performed in async methods not awaited, shouldn't the Dispatcher take priority over the methods?
3. Is there another way (without using the Dispatcher, or using another Window property) to accomplish what I'm looking for?

This is the code used to access/start the Windows:

```
//WindowA:
<Application x:Class="MyNamespace.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="WindowA.xaml">

//WindowA class:
public static WindowA WindowAInstance;
public WindowA()
{
    // unnecessary code hidden
    WindowAInstance = this;
    WindowB b = new WindowB;
}

// WindowB class
public static WindowB WindowBInstance;
public WindowB()
{
    // unnecessary code hidden
    WindowBInstance = this;
}

// this is the code that starts the timers
public static void StartTimersHandling()
{
    Database.RemoveAgents();

    InterfaceChangerTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    InterfaceChangerTimer.Interval = ApplicationArguments.InterfaceChangerTime;
    InterfaceChangerTimer.Elapsed += InterfaceChanger_Elapsed;
    InterfaceChangerTimer.AutoReset = true;
    InterfaceChangerTimer.Start();

    WindowATimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    WindowATimer.Interval = 1000;
    WindowATimer.Elapsed += WindowATimer_Elapsed;
    WindowATimer.AutoReset = true;
    WindowATimer.Start();

    WindowBTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    WindowBTimer.Interval = 1000;
    WindowBTimer.Elapsed += WindowBTimer_Elapsed;
    WindowBTimer.AutoReset = true;
    WindowBTimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: Try to use Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher instead of window.Dispatcher and priority DispatcherPriority.DataBind

Comment: So what happens in WindowA when it visibility changes, is quering DB to update it view? Maybe the problem is with db call, so windows is not shown until response is received from DB?

Comment: @mkonvisar that was the case until I made all database calls async. Besides there is a one second delay between the visibility change and the timer reactivation that makes the queries

Comment: If this is a "wallboard" application then the two windows presumably take up the entirety of the screen? If so, why not simply toggle the `TopMost` property of each window in turn. As long as you don't "hide" either window, there will always be a window in view even if the "correct" window takes a while to bring to the front.

Comment: How are you creating those windows. Are there multiple UI threads?

Comment: @VadimMartynov, using Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher gives me an InvalidOperationException saying that the current thread is not the owner of the window.  
To usr: The first window is created at application start, the second window is created in the first window's constructor. Both are accessed via a Singleton pattern.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath oh sorry I forgot. Change Invoke to BeginInvoke. FinalCode is Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, new Action(() => yourCode));

Comment: `the current thread is not the owner of the window` that is the problem you need to fix. I don't understand the situation completely, but looks like multiple UI threads or multiple dispatchers. That situation is poison. Try creating the 2nd Window in the load event of the first.

Comment: @usr it's only one UI thread as far as I know. "The current thread is not the owner of the window" happens because `ChangeVisibility` is called from a Timer thread.

Comment: @VadimMartynov, Invoke and BeginInvoke result in the same situation.

Comment: @StevenRands TopMost property doesn't work as expected, WindowA is always visible even when setting `WindowA.TopMost = false;` & `WindowB.TopMost = true;`

Comment: UI timers are called on the UI thread. If you are not using a UI timer that's a problem, too, that you should remove. Post more code. Post all code that creates those windows.

Comment: think  Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher will not work, as those are to separate windows with their own UI threads/message queues

Comment: @user I'm using a `System.Timers.Timer`, which is not a UI timer as per the documentation. Can you give me an example of a UI timer? I'll edit the question to show the Singleton pattern.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath Strange, it should work. I even knocked-up a quick example to check and it works as I expected. Are both windows being created by the same application? I'd echo what others are saying and ask that you post the code that creates and displays the two windows.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath
timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };
timer.Tick += (sender, args) => DoYourWork();
timer.Start();

Comment: That piece of code is not very clarifying. Post all that ties this together. The Mail method, caller of this code, where the timer is being created and so on.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I know you're fielding questions left, right and centre, but just one more from me! Am I right in assuming that your application is non-interactive? That is, you are just displaying information that you've retrieved from a database and your users don't interact with it at all? Also, are you hiding the window chrome and making the application effectively full-screen? (I guess that's two questions)

Comment: @StevenRands 1) Yes, the user NEVER interacts with the application. 2) No, the Window chrome is not being hidden for now but I should do it. Does this make any difference?

Comment: @usr please see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're writing a kiosk application (ie. full-screen, non-interactive). If this is the case I think you would be better off having a single window and switching the views inside it, rather than switching between two separate windows. Also, you need to separate the database query work from the refreshing of the window content. Furthermore, I think it would help if the views knew nothing about each other: at the moment your first window is tightly coupled to your second, which is not really a good idea.

In my opinion, if you changed your architecture a little, a lot of the problems you are having would disappear. Here's what I would recommend:

First, just go with a single window. Create two *user controls* (Project > Add User Control), and move your XAML layout from your existing windows into these two new controls. Then make your main window look something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:StackOverflow"
        WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid>
        <my:UserControl1 x:Name="_first" Panel.ZIndex="1" />
        <my:UserControl2 Panel.ZIndex="0" />
    </Grid>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:5" Duration="0:0:5"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="_first"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                            Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
</Window>
```

This is a full-screen window with no chrome that contains your two user controls (essentially the contents of your existing windows). They are layered in a `Grid` element so that one sits on top of the other: I'm using the `Panel.ZIndex` property to force the first control to the top of the pile. Finally, I'm using an animation (triggered when the window loads) that toggles the visibility of one of the controls to hide it after a certain period of time. The animation is set to repeat and auto-reverse, the effect of which is to hide one of the controls, then make it visible again. You can change the `Duration` attribute value to control how long each control "stays" visible; it's set to 5 seconds in this example, which means a 10 second delay between switches.

The key to this working is that the first user control, when visible, must fully obscure the other user control that lies beneath it. This is easy to accomplish by setting the background colour of the control.

Your user controls can contain anything that a window would contain. Here's the example user control XAML that I used:

```
<UserControl x:Class="StackOverflow.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Background="White" Padding="40">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" FontSize="60"
        TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</UserControl>
```

As you can see it's just a `TextBlock` element whose `Text` property binds to a `Number` property defined in the user control's code-behind. I used the same XAML for both user controls, just varying the `VerticalAlignment` of the text so that I could tell which control was visible at any given time.

The code-behind looks like this (it's the same for both, with the exception of the class name):

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            _timer = new DispatcherTimer
                { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), IsEnabled = true };
            _timer.Tick += (sender, e) => Task.Run(async () => await DoWorkAsync());
        }

        readonly DispatcherTimer _timer;
        readonly Random _random = new Random();

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public int Number
        {
            get
            {
                return _number;
            }
            private set
            {
                if (_number != value)
                {
                    _number = value;
                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Number"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        int _number;

        async Task DoWorkAsync()
        {
            // Asynchronous code started on a thread pool thread

            Console.WriteLine(GetType().Name + " starting work");
            _timer.IsEnabled = false;
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_random.Next(4, 12)));
                Number++;
            }
            finally
            {
                _timer.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(GetType().Name + " finished work");
        }
    }
}
```

It basically contains a single `Number` property (which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`) that gets incremented by a "worker" method. The worker method is invoked by a timer: here, I'm using a `DispatcherTimer`, but as I'm not changing any UI elements directly any of the .NET timers would have done.

The worker is scheduled to run on the thread pool using `Task.Run`, and then runs asynchronously. I'm simulating a long-running job by waiting for a period of time with `Task.Delay`. This worker method would be where your database query gets called from. You can vary the gap between successive queries by setting the timer's `Interval` property. There's nothing to say that the gap between queries need be the same as the refresh interval of your UI (ie. the speed at which the two views are switched); indeed, as your query takes a variable amount of time, syncing the two would be tricky anyway.

Comment: I based on your answer to re-create the UI. It works perfectly, now the Window display time is always 7-8 seconds as it should. The UI is also much faster to show the data by using Binding (which I hadn't realized I could use before) than applying the new values by hand. Thank you very much for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` instead of `window.Dispatcher` and BeginInvoke:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, new Action(() =>
    {
        window.Visibility = visibility;
    }));
```

**Updated**
Switch your timer to DispatcherTimer:

```
timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };
timer.Tick += (sender, args) => InterfaceChanger_Elapsed();
timer.Start();
```

Comment: DispatcherTimer is FAR more inconsistent. A 7 seconds elapsetime takes even 25 seconds with DispatcherPriority set to Send (highest according to documentation)